# What is alternative to deprecated ant task APT for jdk 1.6?

Tags: ant, jdk6

I am using jdk 1.6 and my ant project contains task apt from ant build. My ant version is 1.10 but it is showing below error :

Problem: failed to create task or type apt
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

I have tried to build using  version 1.6.5 and 1.8.1 of ant. But still it shows same error.

**Environment configuration :**
JDK : 1.6
ant : 1.10/1.6.5/1.8.1
OS : Fedora 26